# NUnit with TestCaseSource discovers extra unsourced Test in VS2019

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I have an NUnit test in VS2019 using .Net Core 3.1 with a TestCaseSource that supplies a list of 3-Tuples.

It works as expected and the cases I wish to test are discovered and run.

However, the Test Explorer shows the same Test method as a test without source. The result is the "test" is skipped and the results for the group show as inconclusive. Here are the code and Test Explorer image:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int, int, int)[]> TestInput
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new[] { 
                    (0, 2, 3), 
                    (0, 1, 7), 
...


[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestInput))]
public void CalcTotalTime_Given_known_valid_input_Then_returns_expected_result((int,int,int)[] input)
{
...
```

[image]

Since this is just a learning project the code under test is in the test project, so there is only one project and it targets .NET Core 3.1.

The installed NuGet packages are:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v16.7.1
- NUnit v3.12.0
- NUnit3TestAdapter v3.17.0

Comment: Do you want each individual test case to work on (1) three ints? (2) a single tuple? (3) the entire array of tuples? Your code is written to do (3) and I'd expect it to work but I'm not clear what you are actually  trying to do.

Comment: Yes, #3. The input is an array of edges with a start node, end node, and edge length. Combined they form a graph. I'd like the entire graph as the input to the test.

Comment: Try yielding the explicit type... `yield return new (int, int, int)[]...`

Comment: I did try that, without success. I even encapsulated the 3-tuple in a TestData class and returned an instance of that and it has the same result.

Comment: It's likely you have found a bug. :-)

Comment: Thanks, kinda what I was thinking. I'll report it for the NUnit3TestAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce it and it seems like a bug to me with the NUnit3TestAdapter.
Similar issues were found in the past:
https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/559

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can consider writing your unit test like this:

```
[TestCase(0,2,3)]
[TestCase(1,2,3)]
public void CalcTotalTime_Given_known_valid_input_Then_returns_expected_result(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }
```

But as mentioned in the comment, the behavior is not identical to the original code.

Comment: This does something different from the original code... the test is taking three ints. It's OK if that's what the user really wants to do, but that doesn't appeear to be the case.

Comment: You are correct that this is not the same. The test input requires a list of 3-tuples, where each represents an edge on a graph with two nodes and a length.